# `undefined` returned from JS function, but function appropriately console.logs() the value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I fetch data from chrome local storage using this function:

```
function getStorageByKey(key) {
  chrome.storage.sync.get(key, function(obj) {
    var error = chrome.runtime.lastError;
       if (error) {
           console.error(error);
       }
  console.log('function log')
  console.log(obj)
  return obj
  });
}
```

I call it like this:

```
var storage = getStorageByKey('hidden_threads')
console.log("function's return")
console.log(storage)
```

and the logging output is:

```
function's return
undefined
function log
{hidden_threads: Array(1)}
```

I guess this means that the data is being passed through the function appropriately, but I don't understand why `console.log(storage)` happens **before** the function finishing execution.  I assume that's why it is returning undefined, but not sure about the mechanism that causes this.

Comment: This is due to asynchronous execution of the callback function.

Comment: @metersk your logging output is hard to understand. Which is the output `console.log(storage)`? Also what is "function's return"? Can you show us the actual output?

Comment: @fraxture the output of `console.log(storage)` is `undefined`.  `function's return` was just a string marker i used to show the order of things happening.  i guess as it turns out the function isn't actually returning anything.